# Can not compile fortran because dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

```
~$ gfortran hello.f
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcloog-isl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/f951
  Reason: image not found
gfortran: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program f951)
Abort trap: 6
```

I just installed `gcc` using by `brew` and according to the error message how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I have to answer my question because i just figured out my problem by just reinstall `cloog`

Commmand:

```
brew rm cloog
brew install cloog
```

Hope this help! for some people have a problem like me.

I think this problem is related to upgrading of Mac OSX Yosemite and also a `GCC` because nowadays if you want to install `gfortran` you just type `brew install gcc` not `brew install gfortran`, brew notes that gfortran was included to gcc for installation package already.

Comment: I did this, but I still have the problem.  None of the libraries are symlinked to /usr/local/lib

Comment: You got the exact same error message as me? If not, could you please show me your error message?

Comment: It was the same message. I fixed mine by uninstalling `cloog` and then reinstalling it.  I think this problem occurred when I was switching from MacPorts to Homebrew.