# Openmp with mex in Matlab on mac

Tags: macos, matlab, gcc, openmp, mex

I have OS X El Capitan and Matlab R2016a and I would like to use OpenMP, which has previously worked. I have managed to install gcc-5 via homebrew and have openmp working there. I can see from this thread [GCC C/C++ MEX Matlab R2015 Mac OS X (with OpenMP) doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155724/gcc-c-c-mex-matlab-r2015-mac-os-x-with-openmp-doesnt-work) that at least in R2014a, it was possible to insert mexopts.sh manually and edit it. However, I do not have such a file to use in order to redirect the compiler flag (CC) to point at the gcc-5 compiler that works with the -fopenmp flag.

Any suggestions? Am I going entirely the wrong way?

Comment: The sh/bat configuration files are now deprecated in favor of XML files. You can find them in your `prefdir()` and edit them as you like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update for macOS 10.12, MATLAB 2016b:**
The general principle of the following still holds true. Scroll down for changes I had to make.

---

`clang` has been updated to include OpenMP support, however, the version installed with Xcode 7.3.1 does not support OpenMP yet. Instead, it can be installed with [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh). The [previous solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/334250) using [`clang-omp`](https://clang-omp.github.io) does not work anymore, because `clang-omp` has been removed from `brew`.

The following process has been tested with Mac OS X 10.11.6, clang 3.8.1, MATLAB 2016a.

#### Install `llvm`

Install the current version of `llvm` from `brew` (from `Terminal`):

```
brew install llvm
```

#### Modify MATLAB build configuration

Then, copy a default `mex` compiler configuration file to your MATLAB configuration directory. To find the default configuration, enter `mex -setup C++` on your MATLAB prompt. One option should read something like

> `Xcode Clang++  mex -setup:/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/maci64/mexopts/clang++_maci64.xml C++`

(Here and later we will assume MATLAB 2016a is the version used).
Copy `/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/maci64/mexopts/clang++_maci64.xml` to `~/.matlab/R2016a`, and name it `clang++_openmp_maci64.xml` to be able to tell it apart. Open `clang++_openmp_maci64.xml` in a text editor and modify it as follows:
At the beginning, enter different values for name etc, again to be able to tell it apart:

```
Name="LLVM Clang++ OpenMP"
ShortName="Clang++ OpenMP"
Manufacturer="LLVM"
```

Change the definition of `CXX` to point to the location of `clang` as installed with `brew`. At the default location, this should be

```
CXX="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++"
```

Add `-fopenmp -Wall -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include` to `CXXFLAGS`, so it will read

```
CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=$SDKVER -fexceptions -isysroot $ISYSROOT -fobjc-arc -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fopenmp -Wall -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
```

Add `-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -fopenmp` to `LDFLAGS` so it is similar to

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=$SDKVER -Wl,-syslibroot,$ISYSROOT -framework Cocoa $LDBUNDLE $LINKEXPORT -stdlib=libc++ -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -fopenmp"
```

To activate this build configuration, enter at the MATLAB prompt:

```
mex -setup:~/.matlab/R2016a/clang++_openmp_maci64.xml C++
```

#### Modify MATLAB runtime variables

Now, MATLAB has to know about the locations of the libraries at runtime. Check if you have a file [`~/.matlab7rc.sh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabmac.html#bunueg9-5). If not, copy the template from `matlabroot/bin` into your home directory.
Open this file in a text editor. Scroll down to the `mac|maci|maci64)` section (line 188 ff). Add `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib` to `LDPATH_PREFIX`, so it might read

```
LDPATH_PREFIX='/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib'
```

Restart MATLAB.

#### Test configuration

Create a file `mex_par_test.cpp` containing

```
#include "mex.h"
#if defined(_OPENMP)
#include <omp.h>
#endif
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
#if defined(_OPENMP)
    if (nrhs > 0) {
        omp_set_num_threads(mxGetScalar(prhs[0]));
    }
    {
        mexPrintf("If parallel processing is enabled, you should see the line\n\"Hello world from thread x\", where 'x' represents a thread number.\nThere will be %i threads in parallel.\n\n", omp_get_max_threads());
#pragma omp parallel
        {
#pragma omp critical
            mexPrintf("Hello world from thread %i.\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        }
    }
#else
    mexPrintf("SSIMS Toolbox was not compiled with support for parallelization.\n\n");
#endif
}
```

This should compile at the MATLAB prompt:

```
mex mex_par_test.cpp
```

> `Building with 'LLVM Clang++ OpenMP'.
>   MEX completed successfully.`

Calling the compiled function with `mex_par_test` should yield something like

> If parallel processing is enabled, you should see the line "Hello
>   world from thread x", where 'x' represents a thread number. There will
>   be 12 threads in parallel.
>
> `Hello world from thread 0.
>   Hello world from thread 3.
>   Hello world from thread 8.
>   Hello world from thread 1.
>   Hello world from thread 2.
>   Hello world from thread 11.
>   Hello world from thread 4.
>   Hello world from thread 7.
>   Hello world from thread 10.
>   Hello world from thread 9.
>   Hello world from thread 5.
>   Hello world from thread 6.`

#### Update for macOS 10.12, MATLAB 2016b

- MATLAB 2016b stores build configurations and other files in `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2016b` rather than in `.matlab/R*/` in the user's home folder (check `prefdir`).
- MATLAB crashes on startup after update to macOS 10.12 if the setup described above has been used. To get it working immediately, just comment out the `LDPATH_PREFIX` line in `~/.matlab7rc.sh`. In fact, `LDPATH_PREFIX` should not be needed for this combination of OS, `clang`, and MATLAB
- I found I had to reinstall `llvm`: `brew reinstall llvm`
- MATLAB comes with its own version of `libiomp5`, and this should be linked against. Change your build configuration XML (`clang++_openmp_maci64.xml`) so that every incidence of `-fopenmp` is replaced by `-fopenmp=libiomp5`. Add `-L$MATLABROOT/sys/os/maci64` before each occurrence of `-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib`. Finally, linker options should be `-Wl,-rpath,$MATLABROOT/sys/os/maci64:/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib` instead of `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib`. So my `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` now read

  ```
  CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -arch x86_64 -fexceptions -fobjc-arc -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fopenmp=libiomp5 -Wall -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"
  LDFLAGS="-Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl $LDBUNDLE $LINKEXPORT -stdlib=libc++ -L$MATLABROOT/sys/os/maci64 -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,$MATLABROOT/sys/os/maci64:/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -fopenmp=libiomp5"
  ```

This should make the example above compile again and also not crash MATLAB.

Comment: Absolutely FANTASTIC answer!!! THANK YOU! One minor change, in R2016b, the file .matlab7rc.sh is called matopts.sh. It doesn't have the LDPATH_PREFIX (as you mention). Not sure if this part was crucial to getting things working.

Comment: I can confirm that the guide for R2016b also works with R2017b without any new corrections (except the name R2016b becoming R2017b).

Comment: 2017b here. Great thanks! I guess I can call it a day for now.

Comment: Very helpful answer! The guide for 2016b can also be used for R2018b and R2020a. But, when I have the mexPrintf statement inside the parallel construct, the program segfaults.