# Using OpenMP in Mex files in MacOS

Tags: matlab, openmp, mex

I'm using MacOS 10.14 and trying to use the library OpenMP in Mex files with Matlab 2018b. I understand Matlab does not provide support for OpenMP in Mex files in MacOS but I was trying to follow these instructions (made for Matlab 2016 and previous MacOS): 
[Openmp with mex in Matlab on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362414/openmp-with-mex-in-matlab-on-mac)

However, Matlab crashes when trying to compile a C file. Is there any update on this? Is there a way to use GCC instead of Clang?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "crashes" mean? Any error message?

Comment: No, no error message. Basically Matlab closes and I need to restart it. I can see that the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS are not exactly the ones of Matlab 2016 (the ones of the post I mention above) . This is why I am asking if there is any update on these instructions. Also the file ~/.matlab7rc.sh doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Update: I am able to find the ~/.matlab7rc.sh and do the corresponding changes, but I still get the same problem. Matlab closes without any error message. Any suggestion?

Comment: I am working on the same problem. The instructions from the previous post work for me and allow me to compile simple mex files using OpenMP on macOS 10.14, with R2018b and R2020a, using llvm installed with brew. You will not find or use the matlab7rc.sh file with recent versions of matlab.