# Matlab mex without xcode, but with standalone command line tools

Tags: c, xcode, matlab, compilation, mex

I want to compile mex files without installing xcode, using only Command Line Tools (from apple developer center).

Apple Command Line Tools install the compiler and adds standard libraries and headers to the system in a package much smaller than xcode (which is several GBs).

Running mex on linux is possible - I see no reason why matlab mex should require the huge SDKs required for macos. A long evening of trial and error and hacking configuration files hasn't helped. Does anyone have a minimal working example of how to compile a mex file outside matlab, or a simple way to use mex without having xcode installed?

Best Regards, Magnus

Comment: I think you can install `gcc` from homebrew and essentially use the same compiler as linux. I have both on my machine and I can check later if matlab is able to see both.

Comment: Actually I do not think that gcc is supported on mac, I can only use xcode, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway! As you see below, I found the solution myself.

Comment: I happened to stumble on this topic [gcc mex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155724/gcc-c-c-mex-matlab-r2015-mac-os-x-with-openmp-doesnt-work). Have not tried it but it might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks! For now however, Option 2 in my own solution below is working perfectly!

Comment: Another option is to install Homebrew and then fetch GCC. This will allow you to make MEX-files that use OpenMP. You need to compile the MEX-file without using the `mex` command, as in the accepted answer. See also [this answer on Matlab Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/377799-compiling-mex-files-without-the-mex-command).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending more time, I wound up learning more stuff and answering my own question. I'll post my solution here if anyone else needs it in the future.

Make sure the cord is connected to your computer and that MATLAB is installed, and also install the command line tools from apple. Then call the following makefile to compile arrayProduct.c (comes with matlab) from the terminal as follows:

```
make mex=arrayProduct
```

Put this makefile code in the same folder in a file called makefile(edit to your own needs if you have to):

```
all:
clang -c\
    -DMX_COMPAT_32 \
    -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE \
    -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/include" \
    -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/simulink/include" \
    -fno-common \
    -arch x86_64 \
    -fexceptions \
    -O2 \
    -fwrapv \
    -DNDEBUG \
    "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c" \
    $(mex).c
clang \
    -Wl,-twolevel_namespace \
    -undefined error \
    -arch x86_64 \
    -bundle  \
    -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" \
    $(mex).o \
    c_mexapi_version.o  \
    -O \
    -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"  \
    -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64" \
    -lmx \
    -lmex \
    -lmat \
    -lc++ \
    -o $(mex).mexmaci64
```

The above makefile is a bare minimum working example, you should edit it to comply with your requirements.

Edit:
**Option 2**
You can make MATLAB understand how to use the Command Line Tools by editing the xml file containing the compiler options instead. Open the file located at 
/User/username/Library/Application Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2016b/mex_C_maci64.xml

Remove all compiler and linker options related to ISYSROOT. This will make the compiler search for header files in /usr/include etc instead of in the SDK-folder in XCode.

Comment: Thanks, the solution (option 2) works on my machine.

Comment: You might not want to use `MX_COMPAT_32`, unless you MEX-file source code is really old and uses `int` instead of `mwSize` and the like. For more information about what macros to define during compilation, see [this question on Matlab Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/377799-compiling-mex-files-without-the-mex-command).

Answer (score 7):

Well, I have another option here:
Edit the files under `/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/maci64/mexopts` (probably there should be 3.xml file, all needs the same modification).

Locate the `<XCODE_AGREED_VERSION>` portion, comment the whole xml tag, e.g. wrap them with `<!--` and `-->` like this:

```
<!--XCODE_AGREED_VERSION>
            <and diagnostic="Xcode is installed, but its license has not been accepted. Run Xcode and accept its license agreement." >
                <or>
                    <cmdReturns name="defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense"/>
                    <cmdReturns name="defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense"/>
                </or>
                <cmdReturns name="&#10;agreed=$$ &#10; if echo $agreed | grep -E '[\.\&quot;]' >/dev/null; then &#10; lhs=`expr &quot;$agreed&quot; : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` &#10;  rhs=`expr &quot;$agreed&quot; : '[0-9]*[\.]\(.*\)$'` &#10; if echo $rhs | grep -E '[\.&quot;]' >/dev/null; then &#10; rhs=`expr &quot;$rhs&quot; : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` &#10; fi &#10; if [ $lhs -gt 4 ] || ( [ $lhs -eq 4 ] &amp;&amp; [ $rhs -ge 3 ] ); then &#10; echo $agreed &#10; else &#10; exit 1&#10; fi &#10; fi" />
            </and>
        </XCODE_AGREED_VERSION -->
```

Some notes:

1. These files are read only by default, you need to issue `sudo chmod
   644 *` in that directory
2. after comment out all necessary files, issue this command in matlab:
   `mex -setup C++`

Then you are done

Comment: After 'investing' a couple of hours trying to figure out this issue, I'd like to say thank you for the solution.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can confirm it still works with later version (2019b)

Comment: This still worked in MATLAB 2021b, thank you!

Comment: I do not really understand the notes, is the code `sudo chmod
644 *` and `mex -setup C++`has to be run in Terminal? 
The directory is where xml files are located? For exemple /application/MATLAB_R2021b.app/bin/maci64/mexopts

Answer (score 2):

I fully understand you and I'm a big advocate of non-using the enormous Xcode. From my saver [here](https://gist.github.com/martinandersen/1fea529ec04885c63477ccb944394494), run the following to trick `mex` into seeing an accepted license (no `sudo` needed).
Here I use the current version `13.0` at the time of writing, to be adapted.

```bash
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense 13.0
```